# Add answers from unregistered users to the review queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, review

Based on statistics that Shog9 [kindly provided](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192199/158428) we get only a few answers from unregistered users and most of them are bad*:

> the past 60 days worth of Mathematica *answers* produces:
>
> ```
> Registered Unregistered Registered Badness Unreg Badness PctRegBad PctUnregBad 
> ---------- ------------ ------------------ ------------- --------- ----------- 
> 1659       17           128                13            7.72      76.47
> ```

In light of this and given that we have no backlog of review items I propose adding answers from unregistered users to the **Low Quality Posts** review queue.

* Shog9: "I'm gonna define a 'bad' post as one that has been closed, deleted (by someone other than the author), or down-voted below zero."

Comment: In addition, I would also suggest that the first posts and LQ review queue require the same number of reviews in agreement (3) before a decision is made. At present, only 1 reviewer is needed to dequeue it.

Comment: While I don't hate the idea of giving posts from unregistered users a bit better chance of being reviewed, I kinda feel like 17 posts in 60 days isn't really crying out for such a thing. Still, keeping this idea in mind for future reworking of the auto-LQ feed.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for considering it.